# Hybris reference editor - filter using catalog version

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

In my Hybris setup, I have a custom type where one of the fields is a collection of products. In a backoffice screen for the type, I have a multi-reference editor to select the relevant products for the collection.  Now, I want to restrict the products to Online catalogue only (i.e. not show products from Staged product catalogue).  The relevant [documentation page](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/8bab997f86691014852cfbeabd21a5c8.html) indicates that I can use this syntax:

```
<editorArea:attribute qualifier="products">
    <editorArea:editor-parameter>
        <editorArea:name>referenceSearchCondition_catalogVersion</editorArea:name>
        <editorArea:value>{parentObject.catalogVersion}</editorArea:value>
    </editorArea:editor-parameter>
</editorArea:attribute>
```

In my case, however, the custom type does not have the `catalogVersion` attribute, so I would really like to do something like this instead:

```
<editorArea:attribute qualifier="products">
    <editorArea:editor-parameter>
        <editorArea:name>referenceSearchCondition_catalogVersion</editorArea:name>
        <editorArea:value>Online</editorArea:value>
    </editorArea:editor-parameter>
</editorArea:attribute>
```

This does not work (naturally), as the `parentObject.catalogVersion` is the PK.  In my testing, if I specify the actual catalog version PK instead of `Online`, I do get the results I need, yet, obviously, hardcoding the PK is not an option.  So, how can I use the `referenceSearchCondition` to compare with a field of catalog version, referred to by the field in my custom type?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution/workaround(not really ideal) that came to my mind right now after taking a look into the documentation and the accelerator code provided by SAP is doing the following:

1. Create a dynamic attribute which retrieves the PK of the catalogVersion *Online* on the parent (Ex: name it catalogVersionOnlinePK).
2. Then you can access the PK value directly:

   ```
    <editorArea:attribute qualifier="products">
       <editorArea:editor-parameter>
           <editorArea:name>referenceSearchCondition_catalogVersion</editorArea:name>
           <editorArea:value>{parentObject.catalogVersionOnlinePK}</editorArea:value>
       </editorArea:editor-parameter>
   </editorArea:attribute>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I had nearly the same requirement and solved it this way:

```
<wz:editor-parameter>                                
    <wz:name>referenceSearchCondition_catalogVersion_in</wz:name>
    <wz:value>{@customCatalogVersionService.getOnlineCatalogVersions()}</wz:value>
</wz:editor-parameter>
```

in addition, i also needed to make the `customCatalogVersionService` available by adding this to the corresponding `*backoffice-spring.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:cng="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/spring"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/spring
            http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/spring/cng-spring.xsd">

    ...

    <cng:list-extender bean="fixedBeanResolver" property="availableBeanNames">
        <cng:add value-type="java.lang.String">
            <value>customCatalogVersionService</value>
        </cng:add>
    </cng:list-extender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it goes OTTB, but try this

```
<editorArea:attribute qualifier="products">
   <editorArea:editor-parameter>
       <editorArea:name>referenceSearchCondition_catalogVersion.version</editorArea:name>
       <editorArea:value>Online</editorArea:value>
   </editorArea:editor-parameter>
</editorArea:attribute>
```